# Create new user programmatically

Tags: c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a linux user using C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454089/how-to-create-a-linux-user-using-c-c)

Is there any way to create new user from c program in Linux?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454089/how-to-create-a-linux-user-using-c-c

Comment: Do you prefer C system calls or is running an external command in the shell acceptable? This can be tightly integrated into your code with `popen`

Comment: I removed the "linux-kernel" tag because adding a user is a userspace operation, and doesn't involve any special kernel calls.

Comment: yes, exactly I prefer system calls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a fairly complicated process to do everything right. The easiest way for you would be to simply run the `useradd` program, either using `system()` or `fork`/`exec` . Otherwise, if you really, really need to do it in your own code, get the source for `useradd` and study it. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/60929) for info about finding the `useradd` source.

Comment: isn't it possible to "link" to a development package in your distro which contains useradd? That way it would be possible to use it as a library - which would be neat imho.

Comment: I just checked the source, and yes, you don't want to meddle with that for the sake of meddling with that. You stand to create all kinds of nice bugs __AND__ risk breaking your user's (client's?) login systems :)

Answer (score 0):

A user in most Linux systems is not something the kernel is aware of as such. For most systems, it's probably enough to edit the password file (/etc/passwd) accordingly. Of course, you often have to be root in order to be allowed to change the password file.

See [this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-add-new-linux-user-account/) for more on how to add a user. You can of course write a C program that either replicates the steps taken by the `useradd` command, or calls it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `adduser` or `useradd` command found on most systems is a C program that does it.

Creating a user is typically just a matter of adding an entry to `/etc/passwd` and related files, creating a home directory, and copying some files from `/etc/skel` into the home directory.  Look at the source code of `adduser` or `useradd` for details.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

First you can create the user by changing the user database. In the most simple case this is `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. If you want to create an own group for the user, which is the normal case on modern Linux systems, you have to alter `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow`. But you can not be sure that this works, because the system could take the users from a NIS or LDAP domain. In that case the user has to be created on the NIS or LDAP server.

The second way is to execute the operating system command, which does the job. This is `useradd`. There are various way how to do it. The most simple is to call system

```
system("useradd newguy");
```

This involves the execution of a shell. The more advanced way is to do a fork with an `execve()` on the `useradd` binary. But the result is the same.

For examples see man pages [`man system(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system), [`man fork(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fork) and [`man execve(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execve).

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following slightly viable resource:

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO-8.html

On howto integrate shadow support in your program. Mind you, this presumes static linkage with the passwd/shadow libs. This places the (IMHO enormous) burden of providing immediate security updates once a security issue has been fixed in the upstream code (because the statically linked code will have been baked into your application, including the security flows/bugs that were fixed upstream).